# Get roles in .aspx inside MVC membership application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am using an application written with mvc membership and not rolemanager, but I am adding an aspx page to it and want to use existing membership that came with the mvc app. How can I get a list of roles in my aspx page? AND a list of all users? Thanks in advance.

In rolemanger aspx scenario, I would use: Membership.GetAllUsers() AND Roles.GetAllRoles(), but it does not work with the mvc. I need this to work with aspx

```
Imports Nop.Core.Infrastructure
Imports Nop.Services.Helpers
Imports Nop.Core.Domain.Customers
Imports Nop.Services.Customers
Imports Nop.Core

ListBox1.DataSource = EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles()
ListBox1.DataBind()

'this is the listbox on aspx page
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

this is the listbox output, repeated, if there is more than one role per user for each role:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CustomerRole_6E0DFC682B2D3247B3BEEED3063345A95D5742CE33B2761C4CB20A8C0A0AD639
```

Comment: please show your source code where you try to get all roles. this should work identically in MVC as in Web Forms.

Comment: Ok, I didnt see your comment, it was hidden. sorry. this is nopcommerce 2.8. and here is my code on the edit:

Comment: I haven't used nopCommerce, but I would request Roles list by `System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles()`

Comment: Thank you for the comment: when I use system.web.security.roles.getallroles(), first off, i got an error that said "rolemanager not enabled". So, I went to web.config and enabled rolemanager, and ran the page and the listview is blank. absolutely no roles..although I do have 8 different roles.

Comment: If the rolemanager was disabled, how did you originally add the roles?

Comment: i added the roles through nopcommerce backend page. its not an easy system to customize, and their forums not always helpful.

Comment: Ok, this NOT an asp.net membership question. Its a nopCommerce question. I'd suggest adding roles thru membership, but don't understand your needs well enough to know if thats a good idea.

Comment: i will relist with nopcommerce as tags then